# Did the Dock Hierarchy changed with Mavericks ?

Tags: osx-mavericks, accessibility

I'm having some trouble on making an app compatible with Mavericks.

I was wondering : Did Apple change something in the UI element hierarchy for the `Dock` ?

Here is what I have on Mavericks using `Accessibility Inspector`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess not. This is what I get with **Mountain Lion** (*v10.8.5*):

[image]